# PHP Binding a Wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hope Somebody will help me about how I bind a parameter in mysqli when a multiple character wildcard needs to be next to the variable value. I found that it worked for me when creating a SQL statement, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE '%$title%'";
```

However, I tried to bind the variable following the same pattern, and found that it failed. They used this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE '%?%'";
```

It raised this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]:
>   Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared
>   statement in program_name on line......

Can anybody tell me how fix this problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Try either `LIKE ?` then `bind_param("%".$string."%")` or `LIKE '%' || ? || '%'`.

Answer (score 5):

You can bind only data literals not arbitrary query parts.
So, prepare your literal first

```
$var = "%$var%";
$sql = "SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE ?";
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I used same variable twice in where clause in my query, Like this - WHERE (s2.subject_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR c.city_name LIKE '%$keyword%' ). Then can you tell me how I bind this variables.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan I have updated answer as per your comments, see below

Comment: Doesn't this leave a security hole. Specifically if the $var = 'hello%world' you have an unintended placeholder token.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE ? ";
```

and then

```
$title_new =  '%'.$title.'%';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $title_new);
```

**Updated based on user's comment**

To implement below SQL

```
 s2.subject_name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR c.city_name LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

Use below MySqli statement
    s2.subject_name LIKE ? OR c.city_name LIKE ?

```
 $keyword = '%'.$keyword.'%';
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $keyword, $keyword);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $sql="SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE concat ('%',?,'%') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

have one question mark per bind variable. 
For example 
    prepare(SELECT item_title FROM item WHERE item_title LIKE ? and name2 like ? and ...)
The nice thing about prepared statements is that you don't need to worry about quoting the variables.

Then bind all parameters like
    bind_param("ss...", $param1, $param2, ....);