# SQL parameterized query with LIKE '% ? %' PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Search function in php and have created it using a parameterized query to make it secure.

```
$words = $_POST['words']//words is the form that has the words submitted by the user 
$array = explode(',', $words);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");

$stmt = $con->prepare(" SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE ?")
foreach($array as $key) { //searches each word and displays results   
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $key)
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get-result();

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc(){
    echo $row["column_name"]
  }
}
```

however I want **$stmt** statement to be

```
  $stmt = $con->prepare(" SELECT column_name FROM table WHERE column_name LIKE '%?%' ")
```

otherwise people have to type in the entire value of column_name to find it.

Comment: I do it in the execute, `$stmt->execute(array('%' . $key . '%');`... that's in PDO not sure if mysqli supports that.

Comment: @chris85 ^ Yes, that would also work with `mysqli_`. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/24207056/

Comment: it throws an error: Warning, execute() expects  exactly 0 parameters and 1 is given

Comment: Try adding the explode in there.instead.

Comment: Here, try this `LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%')` that should work.

Comment: that works!!, @Fred-ii- make it an answer so i can upvote you

Comment: It has been done ;-) *cheers*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), like this:

```
LIKE CONCAT ('%', ?, '%')
```

Comment: This isn't very flexible. What if you want the wildcard in the middle of the string for example. Their must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
$key="%$key%"
```

Then bind $key.

Also see [PHP Binding a Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872029/php-binding-a-wildcard) for pretty much the same question....

Comment: doesn't work that just crates a string '%$key%' and then it searches the database for column_name with  " '%$key%' " in it.